# While setting value in edit text change the color of the value?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 8 edittext fields some of which are set by the user, on pressing the CALCULATE button the edittext field which are having zero get filled with the calculated value. I want while setting the value in the edittext that has zero the color of the values will change, just to display the change to user.

I am new to android that why i dont know the proper functons.

go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (setFlag) {
                eg1.setText("");
                eg2.setText("");
                eg3.setText("");
                eg4.setText("");
                eg5.setText("");
                eg6.setText("");
                eg7.setText("");
                eg8.setText("");
                tg.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    bg.setOnClickListener(new OnClick());

}


      setFlag = true;
            if (ng1 == 0)
            {
                if(Goal>10)
                    eg1.setText("");
                    else
                        eg1.setText(Float.toString(Goal));
            }




            if (ng2 == 0)
            {
                if(Goal>10)
                    eg2.setText("");
                    else
                    eg2.setText(Float.toString(Goal));
            }



            if (ng3 == 0){
                if(Goal>10)
                    eg3.setText("");
                    else
                        eg3.setText(Float.toString(Goal));
            }



            if (ng4 == 0){
                if(Goal>10)
                    eg4.setText("");
                    else
                    eg4.setText(Float.toString(Goal));
            }



            if (ng5 == 0){
                if(Goal>10)
                    eg5.setText("");
                else
                    eg5.setText(Float.toString(Goal));
            }




            if (ng6 == 0){
                if(Goal>10)
                    eg6.setText("");
                else
                    eg6.setText(Float.toString(Goal));
            }




            if (ng7 == 0){
                if(Goal>10)
                    eg7.setText("");
                    else
                        eg7.setText(Float.toString(Goal));
            }



            if (ng8 == 0){
                if(Goal>10)
                    eg8.setText("");
                    else
                        eg8.setText(Float.toString(Goal));

            }
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?? Show us.

Comment: Did you try anything? This isn't something too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this help you.

```
EditText editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

String textVal=editText1.getText().toString();

if(textVal.equals("0")){
  editText1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Puneet i am just giving you the idea, Just before setting the values in different 8 Edittext. You can check for the value whether it is 0. If 0 then change the color.

```
 if(eg1.getText().toString().trim().equals("0"))
            eg1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        else
            eg1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Above is just a sample code.if you have any query, Please comment.